# Are there any lightweight alternatives to ELK-stack?

Tags: logging, elastic-stack

I have a VPS with 1GB RAM. I want to find an alternative for ELK, because my vps server is too weak. I just need to get logs from logstash and visualize its on the some web gui.

Answer (score 8):

Seq is a decent option, however i don't use it with logstash. you can run it in a container and send all your logs there. I personally use it with my .Net core applications, using Serilog with the Serilog.sink.seq to send the logs to the container. It is definitely not a powerful as the ELK stack but it's works well for small projects. The only downside is you have to use containers to run it on linux.

Website: https://datalust.co/seq

Comment: I think this part is incorrect: "The only downside is you have to use containers to run it on Linux." Seq has windows installer and Docker on Linux. Currently, I use Seq in Windows.

Comment: How is it incorrect, you basically repeated what I said Docker is a container engine. I personally use containers but I called it a downside because not everyone is comfortable using containers.